# Looking for good quality videos explaining design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am looking for good quality videos explaining design patterns.  Can anyone recommend videos I can download and view on my PC.  I am willing to pay for the videos.

Answer (score 10):

I can't believe noone mentioned DNRTV design pattern series:

Jean-Paul Boodhoo on Demystifying Design Patterns

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=63

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=65

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=68

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=71

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=92

Steve Smith on Design Patterns in .NET

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=194

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=196

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=201

Haven't watched this last series myself, but I can guarantee it is great, it is DNR quality man ;)

Jean-Paul Boodhoo's series was great when I first watched it.

Answer (score 6):

See [Channel9 Patterns](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/patterns)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind paying pluralsight has a good course on the topic:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=patterns-library